# Powershell script to export IIS website details

Tags: powershell, iis

I need to extract all the website details created in our IIS server with the following details. As we have more than 80 sites created in our IIS server, I am searching for an easier way to export these details.

details required :

- Website Name
- Bindings
- State
- DB Server name [mapped in connection string]
- DB Name [mapped in connection string]

I am able to extract all the details except DB related available in connection strings using get-website cmdlet. Requesting your help if you know any better way to extract all the information under single file.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find everything you need from the IIS module documentation:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790599.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply Divide. I have already reviewed this, but unfortunately I coudnt able to find the actual cmdlet which can be used to extract IIS website connection string details.

Comment: @user294264 I haven't tried it, but I believe "Get-WebConfiguration" should let you get anything from the Web.config file (where your connection string details should be)